# Sending special characters to pseudo-terminal?

Tags: c, tty

I'm trying to write a C program that creates a pseudo-terminal running a new bash instance, and records all the input and output that goes through it. The eventual goal would be to asynchronously send this to a server, where somebody else could view your terminal activity in real time.

I've completed the pseudo-term creation step, and I can start a new bash instance and log "most" of the input and output. My issue right now is that the pseudo-term isn't properly recognizing arrow keys. They get printed to the screen as ASCII values `(^[[A, ^[[[B, ^[[C, ^[[D)`, instead of moving the cursor around the command line.

Here's the slave portion of the pty, which will run bash:

```
if(pid == 0){ //child 
    struct termios term_settings;

    close(ptyfds.master);

    rc = tcgetattr(ptyfds.slave, &term_settings);
    cfmakeraw(&term_settings);
    tcsetattr(ptyfds.slave, TCSANOW, &term_settings);

    //replace stdin,out,err with the slave filedesc 
    close(0);
    close(1);
    close(2);
    dup(ptyfds.slave);
    dup(ptyfds.slave);
    dup(ptyfds.slave);

    //We can close original fd and use 0,1,2 
    close(ptyfds.slave);

    //Make this process the session lead 
    setsid();

    //Slave side of PTY becomes the new controlling terminal 
    ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 1);

    char ** child_argv = (char **) malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        child_argv[i-1] = strdup(argv[i]); //could be bash, bc, python
    }
    child_argv[i-1] = NULL;
    rc = execvp(child_argv[0], child_argv); 
}
```

And here's the master side of the pty, sending input to the slave and capturing its output.

```
if(pid == 0){ //parent
    fd_set fd_in;
    close(ptyfds.slave);

    FILE *logFile = fopen("./log", "w");

    while(1){
        //Add stdin and master fd to object 
        FD_ZERO(&fd_in);
        FD_SET(0,&fd_in);
        FD_SET(ptyfds.master, &fd_in);

        //intercept data from stdin or from slave out (which is redirected to master) 
        rc = select(ptyfds.master+1, &fd_in, NULL,NULL,NULL);

        switch(rc){
            case -1:
                fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on select()\n", errno);
                exit(1);
            default:
                if (FD_ISSET(0, &fd_in)){ //There's data on stdin 
                    rc = read(0, input, sizeof(input));
                    if(rc > 0){
                        input[rc] = '\0';
                        write(ptyfds.master, input, rc);//send to master -> slave 
                        fputs(input, logFile);
                    }
                    else if(rc < 0){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on stdin\n", errno);
                        exit(1);
                    }

                }

                if(FD_ISSET(ptyfds.master, &fd_in)){ //There's data from slave 
                    rc = read(ptyfds.master, input, sizeof(input)-1);
                    if(rc > 0){
                        input[rc] = '\0';
                        write(1, input, rc);//send to stdout 
                        fputs(input, logFile);
                    }
                    else if (rc < 0){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read master pty\n", errno);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
        }//switch 

    }//while 
}//end parent
```

I've tried messing around with the termios flags [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/rttcsa.htm), but there are none that specify arrow keys.

What do I need to do?

Much of this code came from [here](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html).

Comment: I can't spot any specific c++ code here. Please remove the c++ tag.

Comment: user0042. Sorry, other parts of this code use boost asio, but I didn't notice that the code segments here don't actually c++ code. I changed it.

Comment: FYI -- have you looked at [emPTY](http://empty.sf.net)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have not, but I'm browsing through it now. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Cursor keys (and function keys) send *escape sequences*. These are typically defined&handled by termcap/terminfo, sometimes embedded in the curses library. Setting a `TERM=xterm` environment variable will probably help at least the shell you attempt to execute. (termios doesn't handle terminals, it only manages special character values that should be promoted to signals, like ^D and ^C)

Comment: Maybe bash isn't putting the terminal into character-at-a-time mode and you're getting the normal system tty processing/echoing. Can you verify that sending `^A` to the pty causes bash to move the cursor all the way to the left?

Comment: Comparing output from `stty -a` when all is working and when it's not may be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like the terminal type is not properly set in the pseudo terminal. What is the output of `echo $TERM`?

Comment: You have `if(pid == 0){ //parent` for the parent, but presumably it should use `!=` if `pid` came from `fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a mistake in the example program.
I was able to fix it by moving:

```
rc = tcgetattr(ptyfds.slave, &term_settings);
cfmakeraw(&term_settings);
tcsetattr(ptyfds.slave, TCSANOW, &term_settings);
```

into the master section and replacing `ptyfds.slave` with `STDIN_FILENO`

(This sets STDIN to raw mode, rather than the slave)